# remove all characters from a string

Tags: c++, string

Is there an elegant way to remove characters from a string?
For instance, how do I get from `foo123bar` a string `123`?

I'm aware that there are some similar questions, but my point is, that I don't know a priori if `foo` or `bar` is present.

Cheers!

Comment: Could you be more specific about what `123` is? Is it a substring with a known location, or just a sequence of numerics inside a string of letters? What about `f1o2o3b4a5r`, do you need to be able to convert it to `foobar` to, or do numbers need to be contiguous?

Comment: @dasblinkenlight: it is as I wrote: I might have some characters in front and a might have some behind the `123` part.

Comment: @ezdazuzena: if you just want to know whether "123" appears in the string or not, you can use `std::search`. Suppose the input string is `"foo1234bar"`: is the `4` part of what you want, or part of "some characters behind"? People answering this question are currently guessing what you actually want, it would be better if you told them.

Comment: @SteveJessop: from your example I want `1234`.. I just want to cut away the characters. And people actually gave me quite some nice answers ;)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use **std::remove_if** algorithm
Here is code:

```
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
int main(int argc, char**argv)
{
  std::string str("hello123");
  str.erase(std::remove_if(str.begin(),str.end(),isalpha),str.end());
  std::cout<<str<<std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

output will be:

```
123
```

Comment: There's an issue here that it's UB to pass a negative value (other than EOF) into `isalpha`, and `char` might be a signed type. But you can easily write a function to call `isalpha` correctly, and use that in place of `isalpha`. In practice I think implementations tend to accept negative `char` values to `isalpha` and give a sensible answer, even though they don't have to.

Answer (score 3):

If you have a C++11 capable compiler, you could use [`std::copy_if`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/copy) and lamdas:

```
std::string str = "foo123bar";
std::string dst;

std::copy_if(str.begin(), str.end(), dst.begin(), [](const char ch) { return !isalpha(ch); });
```

Comment: Very neat and beautiful solution, a bit off-topic but which compilers are C++11 capable (is this meaning conforming to the new standard of 2011?)

Comment: @BorisStrandjev As far as I know, GCC 4.6 is pretty up to date, as should Visual C++ 2010 be.

Comment: @BorisStrandjev: There's quite a useful summary [here](http://wiki.apache.org/stdcxx/C++0xCompilerSupport)

Answer (score 0):

I think that using regex is too low-performant for this task. Try:

```
string filtered;
for (int i = 0; i < str.size(); i++)
{
    if (!isalpha(str[i]))
    {
        filtered.push_back(str[i]);
    }
}
```

After that the `filtered` will contain what you need.

Answer (score 0):

Iterate over the `string` and print out non-alphabetic characters:

```
string::iterator iter;

for(iter = myString.begin(); iter != myString.end(); ++iter) {
    if (! isalpha((int)*iter))
        cout << *iter;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess what you mean to do is to remove a substring from a string, not remove digits.

```
string str = "foo123bar";
string sub = "123";
for (auto it = std::search(str.begin(), str.end(), sub.begin(), sub.end());
     it != str.end();
     it = std::search(str.begin(), str.end(), sub.begin(), sub.end())) { 
       str.erase(it, it + sub.size())
     }
```

Comment: I meant removing `foo` and `bar`.. without knowing exactly `123`.. could also be `456`