# Validating input from Integers

Tags: c

Thank you guys for answering my first question, but I have another one. I have this code here
that uses strtol() function. It works, but the problem is that if I enter one of the three options: (d 2) its considered as a string, and if Input (2d) its a string, and (d2) is a string. Is there a way to detect the numbers within the array?

```
  char userInput[256];
    char *end;
    printf("Please enter your name: ");
    scanf("%s", userInput);
    int userName = strtol(userInput, &end, 10);
    if (!*end)
    {
        printf("You have enter an int");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("You have entered a string");
    }
```

Comment: So you are saying that you want the program to ignore any letters that the user input?

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't specific what I want is the user to enter any letters and ignore integers. For example if I enter "C Programming" that is valid, but I enter "2" is not valid or "C2 Programing" thats not valid. I am asking for a name, and names don't contain numbers:) Sorry for the confusion !

Comment: I think [strcspn](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strcspn/) is 1 of the easier ways to check if your string contains numbers.

Answer (score 1):

If you really just need to check to see if string has numbers in it, this will do:

```
int has_ints(char * str) {
    const int len = strlen(str);
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        if (str[i] <= '9' && str[i] >= '0') {
            return 1;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I was going to suggest something like what was in this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9291702/remove-all-characters-from-a-string but your answer is simple.

Comment: Thank you guys, but John I don't know how to use C++ or translate it into C. I came from Java, and C is still pretty knew to me. The code above I don't understand, but correct if I am wrong. It just checks within the array string if it contains a number right?

Comment: Would you guys know how to get the strtol function working with fgets?

Comment: @Leoc you may need to do some reading up on c strings to completely understand this. Basically, loop through an array of type `char` and compare each value against the range of 0-9 in ascii. `char` are just numbers, so we're comparing the value of `str[i]` to be `<= '9'` and `>= '0'`, where `'9'` becomes `57` in ascii, and `'0'` `48`. If the values is between `48` and `57`, it must be a number. I `return 1` so that `if(has_ints(str))` would be true if it has ints in it, and false if not. (0 being false, non-0 being true).

Comment: @Macattack I do understand it as I wrote a program that sees if the user input is valid through ASCII code. I misread your answer and didn't see that you used an int array thus already converting each character to its ASCII form. Please correct me if I am wrong, and thank you!

Comment: @Leoc `char foo[] = {97,98,99,0};` and `char bar[] = {'a','b','c','\0'};` are identical. The compiler converts `'a'` to be `97` when the program is compiled. I passed a `char *` which is just a pointer to a character, it is the common representation of a string in c.

Comment: @Macattack Check the out the code I just posted. It seems to work perfectly. :)

Answer (score 0):

I did this:) works quite beautifully!

```
    int exit = 0;
    int i;
    while (exit != 1)

    {

    char userInput[256] = {0};
    int asciiCode[256];
    int zeroCounter = 0;
    int letterProof = 0;
    int numberProof = 0;
    int specicalCharactersProof = 0;

    printf("\nPlease enter your name: ");
    fgets(userInput, 256, stdin);
    for (i = 0; i < 256; i++)
    {
        asciiCode[i] = userInput[i];

        if (asciiCode[i] == 0)
        {
            zeroCounter++;
        }
    }

    int reSize = (256 - zeroCounter);

    for (i = 0; i < reSize; i++)
    {
        if (asciiCode[i] >= '0' && asciiCode[i] <= '9')
        {

            numberProof = 1;
        }

        else if ((asciiCode[i] >= 'a' && asciiCode[i] <= 'z') || (asciiCode[i] >= 'A' && asciiCode[i] <= 'Z'))
        {

            letterProof = 1;
        }

        else if ((asciiCode[i] >= '!' && asciiCode[i] <= '/') || (asciiCode[i] >= ':' && asciiCode[i] <= '@') || (asciiCode[i] >= '[' && asciiCode[i] <= '`') || (asciiCode[i] >= '{' && asciiCode[i] <= '~'))
            {
                specicalCharactersProof = 3;
            }
    }
   if (letterProof == 1 && numberProof == 0 && specicalCharactersProof == 0)
   {
       printf("\nWelcome %s\n", userInput);
       exit = 1;
   }

   else
   {
       printf("\nInvalid Input.\n");
   }

    }

return(0);
}
```